# React firing unlimited requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

> **What I am trying to do?**

I am trying to call an api that sends information and I want to render the information on to the react app. I have acheived what I wanted to however, there is a problem.

> **THE PROBLEM**

React is firing unlimited request to the api as shown in the image below.

> app.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './css/main.css'

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  fetch(`http://localhost/api/index.php`).then((res)=>{return res.json()}).then(
    (data)=>{
      setData(data)
    }
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {data.length > 0 && (
        <ul>
          {data.map(ad => (
            <li key={info.id}>
              <h3>{info.name}</h3>
              <p>{info.details}</p>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image: React firing unlimited api requests]

Answer (score 3):

### Why is it not working?

The reason why this happens is that you are fetching data and update state on the fly that causing component to rerender, then to fetch data again, set state, rerender (getting stuck in a loop).

### How to solve?

You should use `useEffect` hook (read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)). Also, you can read more about data fetching on official documentation website [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks).

### What will change in your code?

The whole fetch will be wrapped in a `useEffect` hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost/api/index.php`).then((res)=>{return res.json()}).then(
      (data)=>{
        setData(data)
      }
    )
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use  useEffect(). The problem is when you set the data your component rendering from scratch and again fetching data and again setting and again again...

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost/api/index.php`)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>setData(data))
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting the state in the API response itself and state change triggers re-render.

This happens as follows: fetch API call -> Data response -> set state -> trigger re-render -> fetch API call and the cycle continuous and result in infinite API call.

Solution: Call the API inside useEffect, useEffect is a hook that triggers once when the page renders or when its dependency changes.

Update your app.js as follows:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import './css/main.css'
    
    const App = () => {
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=> {
      fetch(`http://localhost/api/index.php`).then((res)=>{return res.json()}).then(
        (data)=>{
          setData(data)
        }
      ),[]
}
    
      return (
        <div>
          {data.length > 0 && (
            <ul>
              {data.map(ad => (
                <li key={info.id}>
                  <h3>{info.name}</h3>
                  <p>{info.details}</p>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put fetch function inside useEffect and inside dependency array define when you want to run it. It will stop React from firing unlimited requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

React calls the body of your component function on each render. In your case you:

- Perform a request,
- Upon completing the request, you set the state of your useState hook,
- The state triggers a re-render,
- The cycle repeats.

So the solution is to use 'life cycles' by using something like [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), in which you can determine when to run your callback (the `fetch()` in your case) - only on mounting the component, or when props change.

Answer (score 0):

```
const renderData = () => {
  fetch(`http://localhost/api/index.php`).then((res)=>{return res.json()}).then(
      (data)=>{
        setData(data)
      }
}
useEffect(() => {
renderData();
},[]);
```